# Where is mdo_import_help in python

Tags: python

I'm a new python user. I'm trying to run some python code code but it
keeps failing because `mdo_import_help` is missing.

The code looks like:

```
from mdo_import_helper import *
exec(import_modules('pySpline', 'tripan', 'functions'))
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'mdo_import_helper'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, 

I am trying to run an aerodynamic simulation 
analysis of a wing.

Problem is :
from mdo_import_helper import *
exec(import_modules('pySpline', 'tripan', 'functions'))

ModuleNotFoundError :
No module named 'mdo_import_helper'

Comment: Removed superflous content. Please also add code in the question, and not as a comment.

Comment: There is nothing named `mdo_import_helper` that comes with Python.  This is obviously a dependency of the code you're trying to run; hopefully its instructions tell you exactly what else you need to install to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

May You should to give [AeroSandbox](https://pypi.org/project/AeroSandbox/) a try. This python package is designed for what You need.

Comment: Hi, thank you, 

I am trying to run an aerodynamic simulation 
analysis of a wing.

Problem is :
from mdo_import_helper import *
exec(import_modules('pySpline', 'tripan', 'functions'))

ModuleNotFoundError :
No module named 'mdo_import_helper'